# Can't create a virtual device in android studio

Tags: android, linux

Every time I try to create a virtual device, android studio throws a permission denied exception. 
The folder (.android) where the api is located has a root access only policy.
How can I unroot the folder or solve the issue?

Comment: is there a reason you can't simply chown this folder?

Comment: Don't know what chown means.

Comment: well google is your friend :P, but in a nutshell (if your username is lingote) run `chown lingote:lingote .android`

Comment: Nice. That fixed it.